# The Global Event Bus & notifications in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, notifications, event-handling, vuejs2, event-bus

l am trying to create a global event bus so that two components Parent-Child can communicate with each other. I have searched around; I have read a lot of articles about good pattern of The Global Event Bus, however, I cannot find any solution to my situation. I want to add a notification feature in my application. This is a file event.js which there are different types of notifications:

**Event.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default new Vue({
methods: {
    notifySuccess(message) {
        this.$emit('notify', 'success', message);
    },

    notifyInfo(message) {
        this.$emit('notify', 'info', message);
    },

    notifyWarning(message) {
        this.$emit('notify', 'warning', message);
    },

    notifyDanger(message) {
        this.$emit('notify', 'danger', message);
    },

    requestError(error) {
        if (error.response) {
            this.notifyDanger(error.response.status + ': ' + error.response.statusText);
        }
    },
},
});
```

A Parent component looks like this

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
    import Event from './js/event.js';

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        created() {
            Event.$on('notify', (type, message) => alert(`${type}\n${message}`));
        }
    }
</script>
```

A Child component looks like this

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" @click.prevent="clickTest"></a>
</template>

<script>
    name: 'header',
    methods: {
        clickTest() {
             Event.$emit('notify', 'success', 'Hello World!');
           }
    }
</script>
```

I will add in the future pop-ups for example notifySuccess displays a pop-up in green color, notifyDanger in red color, notifyWarning in yellow.

How to create an event/method in the Child component in depends of type of nostrification? What am I doing wrong?

PS: Sorry for my bad English. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Event.$emit('notify', 'success', 'Hello World!');` with `Event.notifySuccess('Hello World');`(You defined methods in `Event.js` but didn't use them)
And try to avoid using built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id (like `header`)
Then your code will work without any problem.
See [updated demo](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KsOuOCWR9bLJDVB4NF-).

Comment: Years later, I forgot to thank you for the answer! Now I can see the progress I have made over the years.

The EventBus concept is now being abandoned and there are other alternatives.